# Is $X(k')$ a subset of $X$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an algebraic $k$-scheme in the sense of these notes (http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf), and let $k'$ be a field containing $k$.  Let $(Y, \mathcal O_Y)$ be the $k$-scheme corresponding to $k'$.  Of course, $Y$ consists of a single point $(0)$, with $\mathcal O_Y\{(0)\} = \mathcal O_{Y,(0)} = k'$.  By the $k'$-rational points of $X$, we mean the set of morphisms of $k$-schemes $Y \rightarrow X$.

Now, if $(f,f^{\#})$ is such a morphism ($f$ is the map on topological spaces, $f^{\#}$ is a morphism of sheaves $\mathcal O_X \rightarrow f_{\ast} \mathcal O_Y$), then $f(0)$ is a point in $X$, say $x_0 = f(0)$.  It seems natural to say that $X(k')$ can be identified with a subset of $X$, by the mapping $(f,f^{\ast}) \mapsto f(0)$.  If I'm not mistaken, Milne is doing this in the notes I mentioned.  However, is such a morphism entirely determined by its image?

Clearly $f_{\ast} \mathcal O_Y$ is the sheaf on $X$ given by $U \mapsto k'$ if $x_0 \in U$, and $U \mapsto 0$ otherwise.  If I'm not mistaken, we have a commutative diagram for all $U$ containing $x_0$

$$\begin{matrix} \mathcal O_X(U) & \rightarrow & f_{\ast} \mathcal O_Y(U) = k' \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ \mathcal O_{X,x_0}/\mathfrak m_{x_0}& \rightarrow &\mathcal O_{Y,(0)} = k' \end{matrix}$$ So $f_{\ast}$ is completely determined by a homomorphism of $k$-algebras of the residue field of $X$ at $x_0$ into $k'$.  But can there not be several such homomorphisms?  If $k' = k$, then obviously not.  So at least we can say that $X(k) \subseteq X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $k'$-points of $X$ need not be determined by their image (and I'm not sure where you're seeing Milne treat them as if they were, except in the case $k'=k$).  For instance, if you take $X=Y$, then $X(k')$ is in bijection with the set of automorphisms of $k'$ over $k$ (of which there can be many), but all of these maps send the unique point of $Y$ to the unique point of $X$.

[Here I say points of $X(k')$ are *auto*morphisms of $k'$ because I am assuming $k'$ is finite over $k$, since you are working only with schemes that are finite type over $k$.  In general, if $k'$ is not algebraic over $k$, $X(k')$ would be in bijection with the endomorphisms of $k'$ over $k$, which need not all be surjective.]

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I was mistaken about Milne treating $X(k')$ as a subset of $X$.

Comment: Actually there is something: he says "$X(k')$ is dense in $X$ if the set $X(k')$ is dense in $|X|$."  Does he mean the union of all the images of morphisms of $\textrm{Max } k'$ into $X$ form an (honest) dense subset of $X$?

Comment: Can you give me a page number for where he says that?

Comment: Sorry, don't know why I didn't mention that.  It's A60 on page 503

Comment: He says $X(k')$ is dense in $|X_{k'}|$, not in $|X|$.  Note that there is a canonical bijection between $X(k')$ and $X_{k'}(k')$ (this is by the universal property of $X_{k'}$; note that $X_{k'}(k')$ means the set of $k'$-points of $X_{k'}$ _over_ $k'$).  So identifying $X(k')$ with $X_{k'}(k')$, you can naturally think of it as a subset of $|X_{k'}|$ (since $k'$ is now the base field).

Comment: You are really good at this stuff.  Why does your profile say "failed mathematician?"